# Wordpress if usermeta meta_key exists do this

Tags: mysql, wordpress, key, metadata

I'm sure this is easy for you all but this is all new to me.

Basically, I want to check that if the logged in user has a certain metadata attached to their profile, certain things display on the site.

The user's metadata is stored in the wp_usermeta table which contains umeta_id, user_id, meta_key and meta_value. In essence, I need to see if user_id has a meta_key named 'test'.

I am aware of the get_user_meta() function but I can't get this to work the way I want...

```php
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo(); // wordpress global variable to fetch logged in user info

$userID = $current_user->ID; // logged in user's ID
$havemeta = get_user_meta($userID, 'test', true); // stores the value of logged in user's meta data for 'test'.

if (isset($havemeta)){
    echo $havemeta;
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

The theory of this code is that I check to see if the meta_key 'test' contains a meta_value, if true do X else do Y. The annoyance is that not all users have a meta_key of 'test'. Therefore, if the logged in user doesn't have this meta key, the code doesn't function. Besides, I don't want to check the actual value of the meta key (it can be NULL for all I care), I just want to know if such a key exists for the logged in user.

Any ideas?

Comment: $havemeta is always set right above your if statement, so the if statement will always be the same result, no matter the value. Shouldn't you use something like "if (!empty($havemeta)){"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($havemeta) { echo 'your stuff'; }
```

Comment: if $havemeta is a falsey value (e.g. 0 or "0"), then this will wrongly evaluate to false.  It would be better to do a strict comparison with an empty string:
`$havemeta = get_user_meta( $userID, $field, true );
if ($havemeta === '') { /* do stuff */ }`
or
`$havemeta = get_user_meta( $userID, $field, false );
if ($havemeta === []) { /*do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 10):

## Wordpress >=3.3

There is a caveat with the proposed solution: a meta_key which value is `false` will give false negatives.

**To ask WordPress if a meta_key is set, even if the value is `false`, use `metadata_exists`:**

```php
if ( metadata_exists( 'user', $user_id, $meta_key ) ) {

   ...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

(TESTED) If you put `true` as the last argument, according to documentation, it will return the value of the metadata field. Which means you have to put `false` as last argument.

```
$havemeta = get_user_meta($userID, 'test', false);
```

Then, as said in the other answer, you can check it

```
if ($havemeta)
    echo $havemeta;
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

Comment: The third argument specifies whether to return a single meta value, or an array. And it is false by default: "$single
(boolean) (optional) If true return value of meta data field, if false return an array. This parameter has no effect if $key is left blank.
Default: false" - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta. If the meta value doesn't exist it will either return an empty string or empty array based on this argument.